# Display specific row data in bootstrap modal with edit button click

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I am new to programming and trying to implement bootstrap modal to display row data from a mysql table into the modal window.

I have tried the solution found on stackoverflow "Pull information from mysql table to bootstrap modal to edit" by link. But could not able to display the particular row with the $row['SFID'].

I can pull table data but when I click the edit button in front of any row it always show the last row id

and doesn't display the data in the input box on the modal to edit the data???.

Here I am till now, Please help me out.

```
<table class="table table-bordered" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>SFID</th>
            <th>Company</th>
            <th>Product</th>
            <th>Product Line</th>
            <th>Dealer Class</th>
            <th>Status</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <?php
        $query = "SELECT * FROM tblcustomer";
        $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
        $stmt->execute();

        foreach ($stmt as $row): ?>
            <tr>
    <?php $rowID = $row['SFID']; ?>

                <td><?php echo $row['SFID']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['CompanyName']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['Product']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['ProductLine']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['DealerClass']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['RequestStatus']; ?></td>
                <td style="text-align: center">
                    <div class="btn-toolbar">
                        <div class="btn-group">
                            <a class="btn btn-danger" href="#delModal"  data-toggle="modal"><i class="icon-trash icon-white"></i> Delete</a>

            <?php echo "<a class='btn update' href='#editModal' data-sfid='".$row['SFID']."' role='button' data-toggle='modal'>Edit</a>"; ?>
 </div>
                    </div>
                </td>
             </tr>
     <?php endforeach; ?>
 </table>
```

---

```
     <div id="editModal" class="modal hide fade in" style="display: none; ">
 <div class="modal-header">
    <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</a>
    <h3>Edit Customer Details</h3>
</div>
 <div>
<form class="contact">
   <fieldset>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <?php echo $row['SFID']; ?> 
        <ul class="nav nav-list">
        <li class="nav-header">SFID</li>
        <li><input class="input-xlarge" type="text" name="mysfid" id="mysfid"></li>
        <!--<li class="nav-header">Company</li>
        <li><input class="input-xlarge" value=" " type="text" name="mycompany"></li>
        <li class="nav-header">Dealer Class</li>
        <li><input class="input-xlarge" value=" " type="text" name="mydealerclass"></li> -->
        </ul> 
     </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
 </div>
 <div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn btn-success" id="submit">Approved</button>
      <a href="#" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>
 </div>
</div>
```

---

```
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('a.edit').click(function(){
    var sfid = $(this).data('sfid');
    var company = $(this).data('company');
    var dealerclass = $(this).data('dealerclass');    

    $('#mysfid').val(sfid);
    $('#mycompany').val(company);
    $('#mydealerclass').val(dealerclass);
    });

    });
    </script>
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: @LuzanBaral above page link can't working see db error.

Comment: @GanganiRoshan You can find the same updated tutorial here https://justcode.me/php/how-to-load-mysql-data-in-bootstrap-modal-body-using-ajax/

Comment: @LuzanBaral Thanks for update.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<table class="table table-bordered" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>SFID</th>
            <th>Company</th>
            <th>Product</th>
            <th>Product Line</th>
            <th>Dealer Class</th>
            <th>Status</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <?php
        $query = "SELECT * FROM tblcustomer";
        $result = mysql_query($query);
        $i=1;
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
        {
    ?>
            <tr>
    <?php $rowID = $row['SFID']; ?>

                <td><?php echo $row['SFID']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['CompanyName']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['Product']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['ProductLine']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['DealerClass']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['RequestStatus']; ?></td>
                <td style="text-align: center">
                    <div class="btn-toolbar">
                        <div class="btn-group">
                            <a class="btn btn-danger" href="#delModal"  data-toggle="modal"><i class="icon-trash icon-white"></i> Delete</a>

                            <a class="btn update" href="#editModal<?php echo$i?>" data-sfid='"<?php echo $row['SFID'];?>"' data-toggle="modal">Edit</a>
                            <!--Yor Edit Modal Goes Here-->
                            <div id="editModal<?php echo $i; ?>" class="modal hide fade in" role="dialog" ria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                             <div class="modal-header">
                                <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</a>
                                <h3>Edit Customer Details</h3>
                            </div>
                             <div>
                            <form class="contact">
                               <fieldset>
                                <div class="modal-body">
                                    <?php echo $row['SFID']; ?> 
                                    <ul class="nav nav-list">
                                    <li class="nav-header">SFID</li>
                                    <li><input class="input-xlarge" type="text" name="mysfid" id="mysfid"></li>
                                    <!--<li class="nav-header">Company</li>
                                    <li><input class="input-xlarge" value=" " type="text" name="mycompany"></li>
                                    <li class="nav-header">Dealer Class</li>
                                    <li><input class="input-xlarge" value=" " type="text" name="mydealerclass"></li> -->
                                    </ul> 
                                 </div>
                                </fieldset>
                            </form>
                             </div>
                             <div class="modal-footer">
                                <button class="btn btn-success" id="submit">Approved</button>
                                  <a href="#" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>
                             </div>
                            </div>

                             </div>
                    </div>
                </td>
             </tr>
     <?php $i++; } ?>
 </table>
```

Comment: Thanks Ashish, I am getting the first row data in the modal by clicking the Edit button of that row. If I click other row button then I get no data that means it's working perfectly, now I need to figure out to display the next row data with the button.

Comment: You want to display next data on Modal window by cliking "**Next**" Button from **Modal Window**?

Comment: Thanks Ashish, after a small change It's working as I required. Thanks for your help.

Comment: welx..
<script>
for(var i=1; i<=<?php echo $num_details;?>; i++)
{
 $("#editModal"+i).animate({"width":"1100px","left":"30%"},3000,'easeInCirc');
}
</script>
//$num_details = no. of elements from ur query
Try this js styling it will give popup effect for ur modal. (Adjust css properties as per ur requirements)

Answer (score 0):

take $i = 1 above for loop and increament it in each iteration of for loop..so it will take each records

**Your Form**

```
<a class='btn update' href='#editModal<?php echo $i;?>' data-sfid='".$row['SFID']."' role='button' data-toggle='modal'>Edit</a>
```

**Modal Window**

```
<div id="editModal<?php echo $i;?>" class="modal hide fade in" style="display: none; ">
```

Comment: Thanks Ashish for taking time to look in to my problem. I tried your suggestion but by adding $i value in the div id of the modal changes the id of the modal and it doesn't open by clicking the button.

Comment: Disregard my previous reply, my mistake. I did't add the same in href as suggested. I did the changes and tested it but still no change in the output. The Modal window opens but no value in the input box and still select the last record from any button.

Comment: I used the solution of Ashish and got each row with unique modal id but modal window doesn't open. Any suggestion why the windows is not opening on button click. Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you fill the edit modal with the `$row` data, which by then, is on the last item.

To get data for a specific row, you could create a javascript object/array and then fetch the data by making use of the `data-rfid` parameter in the "Edit" link. Or you can fetch the row with Ajax for example.